# Moving values from FPU to Registers and vice-versa

Tags: assembly, x86

So I have some trouble understanding how values are stored/moved between different places(FPU/Memory/Registers). I already tried looking into the manual and googling, did not find anything useful though. So I have written the following code:

```
global _floTest
_floTest:
fld dword[esi-8]    ;Load value into st0
fst dword [test]    ;store st0 into [test]

mov EAX,[test]      ;this line is useless
mov EAX,5
mov [test],EAX


fild dword[test]    ;load st1 from [test]
fsub st0,st0        ;st0 = 0
fadd st0,st1        ;fadd st0,st1
ret
```

_flotest is a function called by a c program which takes a float as an input and returns a float. The target assembler is NASM.

The main thing I do not understand is, that the middle part (EAX) literally has zero impact on the output of the function, the function always returns the given value. I can do arbitrary operations on EAX and it will always return the initial value. If I move 5 into [test] and then load st1 from [test] shouldn't st1 have the value 5?

Comment: FPU is a stack architecture. `FILD` will load into `st0` which you then zero out, so it doesn't matter what you loaded. PS: you also unbalance the fpu stack.

Comment: An addendum to what RossRidge said about unbalancing the FPU stack:The FPU stack is very limited, as it only has 8 slots. You do two operations that put a value on the FPU stack-`fld dword[esi-8]` and `fild dword[test]`. None of your instructions attempt to pop the extra value off the FPU stack.The result will be in _ST(0)_ as a return value (and will be cleaned up by the CALLER) but you have an extra value on the FPU stack that wasn't there when the function started. Because of this, if you were to call `_floTest` 9 times, the 9th time would overflow the FPU stack yielding incorrect results.

Comment: `;this line is useless` What is that for? Are you asking *why* that line is useless? Or do you already know why, you just left this in to help make the question extra-confusing?

Comment: Single-step through your code in a debugger, watching how the registers change.  That should help you understand how the x87 register stack works.  Also see [this x87 tutorial](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html), and other links in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)